# Javascript Drag and Drop DataTransfer Files don't have type

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, file-type

So I'm trying to use drag and drop with **IE11** (all browsers really, but the bug is in IE). I only want certain kinds of files uploaded, and no folders.
When I get into the drop event, I scan the `dataTransfer.data.files` array to make sure that we are only processing files that are supported, and no folders.
Well I got some weirdness that is happening when I try to drag and drop a javascript file. When I check the files array, and specifically look at the `type` property on the `FileObject` in the file list, I have no `type`. Specifically I have a type of `""` (empty string).
On every other browser, I am able to read the type and determine what it is. However, *it's just on IE that I'm having this trouble.*

---

#### Why does `type` property not exist on javascript files from a drop event? Could it just be this machine? If so, what could cause this?

---